# Transparent SWT Canvas

Tags: eclipse, swt

I would like to make the background of an SWT Canvas transparent, so that other widgets can be seen behind it.

I have tried setting alpha to 0 and filling the canvas with a rectangle and also using the option SWT.NO_BACKGROUND to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, it is not possible with SWT to place widgets on top of each other in this way (in a cross-platform manner). Transparent backgrounds won't allow other widgets to be seen. Also any clicks on the transparent pixels won't be delegated to the widgets behind.

But you can place shells on top of each other. And you can create transparent shells or shells with irregular bounds. See the Shell examples in the [Snippets](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/#shell). This is not the same, but depending on what you want to achieve, it might suffice.

Comment: It's possible to place widgets on top of each other using FormLayout.  But I don't know how to make a Canvas transparent.

Comment: False, you can place controls on top of each other. Using the setBounds position and giving it layoutData that tells it to be excluded from the layout.

Comment: OK, obviously you can do that, but that was not the question. It's about transparent background. I'll clarify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do it on **Linux (GTK)**. (However, it *doesn't* work on Windows. (Don't know about MacOSX.))

Just `setBackground` to RGBA with alpha-channel. E.g:

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE);
canvas.setBackground(new Color(canvas.getDisplay(), 100,100,100,100));
//Note the last argument (I'm setting not only R, G, B, but also A).
```

You don't even need `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND`, `SWT.TRANSPARENT` or other style flags.

P.S.: You shouldn't create colors in this way. Colors are to be disposed using dispose. Assign newly created color to variable to be able to reuse it and free it. I created color "inline" just for simplicity of example.

Additional note: don't set alpha-channel to 0. Although lesser value should mean more transparent, in reality it doesn't work with value 0, only with 1 and above. Probably, it considers 0 as unset or etc.

Comment: I've tried this with SWT 4.712 on Windows and it did not work. :(

Comment: @ThomasS., yes, you're right. It doesn't work on Windows. At least, not in my Windows 7 virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I had success with following transparent control:

```
final Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.TRANSPARENT);
composite.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener() {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        event.gc.drawString("hello world", 0, 0, true);
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, this does not work on OS X or Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
shell.setAlpha(180);
```

The value can be set ranging from **0** to **255**. **0** means transparent and **255** means solid colored background

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 new Canvas(parent, SWT.TRANSPARENT);
```